# Pass loop variable as function parameter in HTML <input> onclick attribute with vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I wanted to create a **simple todo list** in `vue.js` to get myself comfortable with it.

Now, I have placed a remove button after each item. For that purpose, I have added a `remove()` function in javascript with a parameter `id` which is the id of the todo list item as well as `onclick` attribute with the button. But the problem is I cannot find a way to pass item (loop variable created using v-for) `id` as a parameter to `remove()` function inside `onclick` attribute.

So, far my script looks like this...

**HTML**

```
...
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">
        {{ item.label }}
        <input type="button" value="x" onclick="app.remove(item.id)">

        <!-- item.id does not work -->
    </li>

    <li>
        <input type="text" v-model="new_item" onkeypress="app.input_keydown(event)">
        <input type="submit" value="+ Add" onclick="app.add()">
    </li>
</ul>
...
```

**JS**

```
...
data: {
    items: [
        {id: 1, label: "One"},
        {id: 2, label: "Two"}, 
        {id: 3, label: "Three"}, 
        {id: 4, label: "Four"},
    ],

    add: function() {
        // let item = prompt("Add Item", "New Item");

        if (app.new_item) {
            app.items.push(app.new_item);
        }
    },

    remove: function(id) {
        for (index in app.items) {
            if (app.items[index].id == id) {
                app.items.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    },
}
...
```

And my *simple* todo list looks like this...

[image: Simple Todo List in vue.js]

Also, I would like to know if in case I have to pass a loop variable in **any** HTML attribute, how would I do that?

Comment: Create a snippet. What does your `remove()` function receive as `id` param? Haven't you console.logged that? Also, I wouldn't recommend using `onclick`, but `@click` instead.

Comment: Actually, I was getting a `ReferenceError` in the console stating that `'item' is not defined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use Vue.js special event handlers instead of html one.
`onclick="app.remove(item.id)"` should be `@click="remove(item.id)"`.

also you have to extract `add` and `delete` methods to `methods` property. They can not be in `data`.